# processing large data file from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I have a large data files in parquet format stored on s3. The files can contain upto 48 million records, which need to be processed.

My current stack in Spring boot/K8, but i dont think this will work in this context.

The data is updated once a week, so processing it and storing in a DB seems pointless.
I could potentially be doing: Millions of single row queries OR 100's of queries which return 100K rows. So if the latter i would need to send this across the wire..

What could i potentially use to query the data efficiently? EMR? Athena?

Comment: I see no issue with using Athena. It can easily handle the scale, and it has SQL flexibility. If you need millions of single-row queries, you should consider also uploading it to a DynamoDB.

Comment: If you are querying single files, then you can use **S3 Select**. Otherwise, use **Amazon Athena** since it can scan multiple files in one query.